# How to configure environment on webjobs sdk?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a dotnet console app using webjobs sdk and I´m not able to find how to get the configuration file correctly based on the environment. My code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var builder = new HostBuilder();
     var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environment");

  builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
  {
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
  });

 ...
```

[image: environment]

After that I create 2 files: `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`. When I´m debugging, even with the variable set to production, I always get the `appsettings.json` values and not the `appsettings.Production.json` value. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Setting the `AddJsonFile` with `optional: false` for `appsettings.Production.json` - does it fail loading?

Comment: While im debugging not, but doesnt change nothing.

Comment: Well it confirms that the file is being loaded. Are you sure the variable you are reading is present in both files and overwritten, or only i the production file?

Comment: yes, sure. and its beeing copied always.

Comment: What do you mean by "copied always" ?

Comment: on the appsettings file theres a property to copy the file to the bin folder when deployed,

Comment: While debugging, have you Watched the IConfiguration object and found your variable(s) inside that?